# Javascript using select value in function

Tags: javascript, html

Not sure what the problem is, also not a javascript coder at all. Can someone shed some light on what I am missing.

The main problem I am having is trying to make this a bit more dynamic based on the selection of a select input. if I comment out the first two variable entries and set the `stropt` variable to something static that would identify one of my div's then it works fine.

```
aChecked = false;

function checkByParent() {
    var sel = document.getElementByID("me");
    var stropt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    //var stropt = 'test2';

    var collection = document.getElementById(stropt).getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    if (aChecked === false) {
        aChecked = true;
    } else {
        aChecked = false;
    }
    for (var x = 0; x < collection.length; x++) {
        if (collection[x].type.toUpperCase() === 'CHECKBOX')
            collection[x].checked = aChecked;
    }
}
```

Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sasatek/b654V/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `getElementByID`, which is a mistake it should be `getElementById`

Like this

```
aChecked = false;

function checkByParent() {
    // var sel = document.getElementByID("me");
    var sel = document.getElementById("me");
    var stropt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    //var stropt = 'test2';

    var collection = document.getElementById(stropt).getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    if (aChecked === false) {
        aChecked = true;
    } else {
        aChecked = false;
    }
    for (var x = 0; x < collection.length; x++) {
        if (collection[x].type.toUpperCase() === 'CHECKBOX')
            collection[x].checked = aChecked;
    }
}
```

Javascript & DOM api is written in [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)

Comment: damn I knew it was something simple. I think I was stung by that same exact thing a while back. ghrr. Thanks!

Comment: you know, jsfiddle should catch that... instead it throws a perfectly written java script message!